# Can't download PyQt5 on mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt, pyqt5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0caZP.png)when running the code, an error occurs, but I installed PyQt5, but an error occurs in the terminal when installing extensions

reinstalled PyQt5 but nothing changed

Comment: What is the description of the image you included?

Comment: Please don't share code using screenshots; copy the code (and any output/errors) into your question so that it can be more easily referenced

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If multiple python versions exist on your machine, you should make sure you are running your code using an interpreter environment with **PyQt5** installed.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Python:Select Interpreter
3. Choose the correct interpreter.